# Conda packages work in Juypter Notebooks but not Terminal Python

Tags: python, opencv, path, anaconda

I want to import OpenCV for a project. I have installed the package using Anaconda Navigator: opencv shows up when calling 'conda list' from the command line (Mac), and I can import and access it from Juypter notebooks.

However, when I try to access opencv from python in the terminal, by entering python and importing opencv, I get an error message saying the package was not found.

I've checked that the terminal is using the Anaconda version of python, and noticed that opencv is absent from my list of python installed packages (using help("modules") in python).

I am struggling to figure out what the discrepency between the access to packages that my Juypter notebooks has, and the python operated from the terminal, and how I can bridge them.

I have tried pip installing opencv, but the package still does not appear under my installed packages (calling help("modules") in python, Terminal). I have uninstalled it to reduce the risk of incompatibility.

I am at a loss as to how to import opencv for use in applications designed in editors outside Juypter Notebooks.

Comment: Looks like you have multiple python installed in your laptop. Make sure that your "python" command is pointing to your desired python version.

Comment: I believe I do have multiple pythons, but 'which python' (in the terminal) and 'import sys, sys.executable) both return the same path '/Users/EyreCraggs/anaconda3/bin/python'. So I am clueless as to why the importing opencv works on Notebooks but not in the terminal

Answer (score 0):

In your notebook, run this command to see which `python` executable you're running

```
import sys
sys.executable
```

Then from the CLI run `which python` to see which `python` it runs. If the paths are different, you're running different executables and OpenCV isn't installed on the CLI one. You'll need to change your `$PATH` variable or provide the full path to get the desired one

Comment: Both methods return the same /Users/EyreCraggs/anaconda3/bin/python. Does that mean that the $PATH is not the issue?

Comment: check `sys.path` on both to see where it's importing from